# Convert JSON Formatting - Dynamic Classes in C#

Tags: c#, json

Hope you guys are ok!

I have a class in WebAPI as below, which is being returned by REST call:

```
public class Record
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public List<Data> Data{ get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

which gets converted to below format:

```
[{
    "ID": "228694",
    "Data": [{
            "Name": "Application Name",
            "Value": "Customer Self-Service Website"
        }, {
            "Name": "Application Type",
            "Value": "Content Access Software"
        }, {
            "Name": "Criticality Rating",
            "Value": "High"
        }, {
            "Name": "Compliance Rating",
            "Value": "Medium"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "ID": "228696",
    "Data": [{
            "Name": "Application Name",
            "Value": "Customer Support Platform"
        }, {
            "Name": "Application Type",
            "Value": "Enterprise Software"
        }, {
            "Name": "Criticality Rating",
            "Value": "Medium"
        }, {
            "Name": "Compliance Rating",
            "Value": "Low"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Is there a way I can get the data in following format?

```
[{
    "ID": "228694",
    "Data": {
        "Application_Name": "Customer Self-Service Website"
        "Application_Type": "Content Access Software"
        "Criticality_Rating": "Medium-High"
        "Compliance_Rating": "Medium"
    }

}, {
    "ID": "228696",
    "Data": {
        "Application_Name": "Customer Support Platform"
        "Application_Type": "Enterprise Software"
        "Criticality_Rating": "Medium-High"
        "Compliance_Rating": "Medium"
    }
}
```

]

So basically I want to convert Name property of Data Class to Key and Value property to Value and have one object rather than array of Data class.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% clear on the information in the question. Are you saying you're generating and returning this data, or are you saying you're receiving this data and want to transform it?

Comment: Just to add, this is all dynamically presented by REST Call, i.e. NAME can be anything if I pass on different query object, although it would be same for all the objects in that specific JSON, but every REST call can have different values in NAME

Comment: I am getting this data from another API call, I always get data in NAME - VALUE pair, but I want to convert NAME to key and VALUE to value but looking for something which is dynamic so that if NAME is anything apart from the above mentioned keys, that gets added as well. Maybe I am asking for too much.

Comment: Another Example:
```
[{
    "ID": "228694",
    "Data": [{
            "Name": "Device Name",
            "Value": "Customer Self-Service Website"
        }, {
            "Name": "Device Type",
            "Value": "Content Access Software"
        }
    ]
}]
```
should get converted to 
```
[{
    "ID": "228694",
    "Data": {
            "Device_Name": "Customer Self-Service Website"
            "Device_Type": "Content Access Software"
        }
}]
```

Comment: can you show the response from API call, before  you converted to your own class

Comment: Make `Data` a `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a new Response class, with the format you want (ID, Data properties), and you can make an extension class or another method to map your current Record class to that new Reponse class.

Comment: Sorry I am not a pro in C#, so did not understand anything. But just another comment - I want to create a class on run time with NAME as name of the property  and VALUE as its value.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, maybe not the best way but it worked.
I looped through all the data array an created new JSON using assigning Name to key and VALUE to value.